# Simple Filename/Path Regex

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex expression that I will use in a redirect plugin in wordpress.

I have a bunch of legacy URL's that look like this:

```
/article.php/281/19/0 
/article.php/383/20
/article.php/28/2/1
```

etc...

Essentially I want to create a regex that will strip off anything beyond the first set of numbers.

e.g. `/article.php/281/19/0` transforms to `/article.php/281`

Comment: what language? what regex flavor? what was your best try?

Comment: `.*\.php/[^\/]*` will match everything until the second `/`, if there is one.

Comment: @KurzedMetal - haven't tried as it's relatively urgent and I don't want to break a production site.  Flavor and language - no idea... it will be used in the Yoast Premium Wordpress plugin so doesn't give any more details than the following: http://kb.yoast.com/article/142-what-are-regex-redirects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Yoast, you can use

REGEX:  /(article\.php\/[0-9]+)/

NEWURL:  /$1/

Based on: https://yoast.com/wordpress-seo-premium-1-1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
(^\/\w+\.\w+\/\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP6bP2/1)